# Как удалить колонки в DataFrame по маске

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Дан df:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'd_1': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd_1': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd_1': 1},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd_1': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd_1': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd_1': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'd_1': 0},

                  {'id': 2, 'b': 1, 'd_1': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd_1': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd_1': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd_1': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd_1': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd_1': 1}])
```

Как можно удалить все колонки, у которых в название есть `'_1'`? В примере привел для краткости только одну такую колонку, но в реально примере их конечно же больше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [.str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
res = a.loc[:, ~a.columns.str.contains("_1")]
```

результат:

```
In [160]: res
Out[160]:
    id  b
0    1  1
1    1  2
2    1  2
3    1  2
4    1  2
5    1  2
6    1  4
7    2  1
8    2  2
9    2  2
10   2  2
11   2  2
12   2  2
```

Comment: Спасибо, вот такой еще ответ нашел после публикации вопроса: a = a[a.columns.drop(list(a.filter(regex='_1')))]

Comment: @ChikChirik, почему бы не оформить это в виде ответа? ;)

Comment: так и сделал)))

Answer (score 3):

Еще возможен такой вариант:

```
a = a[a.columns.drop(list(a.filter(regex='_1')))]
```

Answer (score 3):

еще пара способов:

```
cols = [x for x in a.columns if not "_1" in x]
res = a[cols]
```

и

```
res = a.drop(a.filter(regex='_1').columns,axis=1)
```